Error CS0201; Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"
I'm new to coding and i'm trying to make the Alien take the Damage int from the lazer script so it gets hurt but I can't fix this error.
Line 31 is what failed
"LazerObject.GetComponent().Damage;"
"Assets\Scripts\AlienAI.cs(31,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"
I have searched for what this means, and I can't find how to fix it.
(Ignore the Defense and Random number Variables)
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class AlienAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent myNavMeshAgent;
    public float Sight = 5.0f;
    public Transform Worker;

    [Header("Important")]
    public int Health;
    public Camera m_Camera;
    public GameObject Camera;
    [SerializeField] string SoldierTag;
    [SerializeField] string WorkerTag;
    public LayerMask LazerMask;
    public GameObject LazerObject;



    public float Defence = 5;
    public float RandomNumber = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myNavMeshAgent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
        Defence += RandomNumber;
        LazerObject.GetComponent<Lazer>().Damage;

    }

    void Awake()
    {
        RandomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-2f,10f);
    }    
    void Update()
    {
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, Sight);
        foreach (Collider nearbyObject in colliders)
        {
            if(nearbyObject.tag == WorkerTag)
            {
               myNavMeshAgent.SetDestination(nearbyObject.transform.position);
            }
            if(nearbyObject.tag == SoldierTag)
            {
               myNavMeshAgent.SetDestination(nearbyObject.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }





}

I'm trying to have the alien take the Damage int from the Lazer's code to take damage but before it takes the damage the defense stat blocks as much damage as it can.

Politness would have been to mark the line that fails which i guess is LazerObject.GetComponent<Lazer>().Damage which Im guessing is a variable? on the other class and then you failed to complete the what to do with it...

Is that the whole comment it shows 3 dots like there's more

Well yes there are 3 dots. Because sadly  you need to decide what it is you meant to do with it. So the rest is over to you

The reason that line giving you an error because it is incomplete, you need to complete your statement. But since there isn't much details on what Damage is it's hard to tell but it should look something like this:
void Start() {
        myNavMeshAgent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
        Defence += RandomNumber;
        Health -= LazerObject.GetComponent<Lazer>().Damage;
    }

